# cannot upload files to Google cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I tried to upload a file via Google cloud shell,
but when I run `ls .` I don't see any file uploaded into the current dir.

the destination dir has 0777 access permission, and I use a clean incognito browser (no extension enabled).

[image]

Comment: When the upload finished, did it show the green circle with a checkmark?

Comment: yes, @jabbson    ------------

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files are uploaded to your home, not to the current dir. If you saw the green checkmark, the file should have been uploaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks, @Adrian. how can I upload the files to the current dir directly? without coppying them from $HOME dir.

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible using the three dot menu. You can use the Cloud Shell editor to upload files directly to specific dirs. Right-click a folder in the file explorer and select upload files.

Alternatively you can always move them from your $HOME dir. We are exploring several improvements to the upload/download features from the three dot menu, including dir selection, but we still don't have specific plans or a timeline.